# How to edit properly a configuration file of a service and make sure it is loaded in the service with Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible, devops

When I'm developping Ansible Playbook, there's something I found annoying when I'm using handlers to trigger reload of configuration file. For example, if I consider editing a InfluxDB configuration (but it can be any services) :

```
- name: Update configuration influxdb
  template:
    src: influxdb.conf.j2
    dest: "/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf"
  notify:
    - restart influxdb
```

If my handler "restart influxdb" doesn't work (because I done an error in my Ansible script, or any other causes), there is no proper way to execute the handler again, because the template is writed.

Result I've go is that the target node is not in a good configuration because the service is not restarted (I have to do it manually).

How to make sure my new configuration is applied to the service in a idempotent way of think ?

ps : I edited my question to make it more clear to answer

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Fix your processes and do not develop/test code on production systems. And if your tested code falls on production and you fix it manually, you've got bigger problems than "how to execute handlers".

Comment: Mmm, I'm not agree, I'm sure that there is an elegant solution to edit config file and make sure it loaded though Ansible. I hope somebody in the community has got a solution.

Comment: Edit done to make my question more clear (and direct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several months practicing Ansible, I've got the answer of my interrogation.

It's an Ansible designing purpose habit to take. When I design a new role that aim to set-up a new service, I have two things to do and not forget :

- Flush the handlers though the yaml command

`- meta: flush_handlers`

 - After flush, testing the service is up, for example on a mysql service 

    `- name: Start and enable the service
      service:
        name: mysql
        state: started
        enabled: yes
    - name: Ensure mysql port is started
      wait_for:
        port: 3306
        delay: 3
        timeout: 300`

If my configuration is wrong, my handler will be executed before the service execution test (thanks to the flush_handlers), so the service test will fail, and I can fix my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

During development phase you may want to enable [force-handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html#handlers-and-failure) option:

> When a task fails on a host, handlers which were previously notified will not be run on that host. This can lead to cases where an unrelated failure can leave a host in an unexpected state. For example, a task could update a configuration file and notify a handler to restart some service. If a task later on in the same play fails, the service will not be restarted despite the configuration change.
>
> You can change this behavior with the `--force-handlers` command-line option, or by including `force_handlers: True` in a play, or `force_handlers = True` in ansible.cfg. When handlers are forced, they will run when notified even if a task fails on that host. (Note that certain errors could still prevent the handler from running, such as a host becoming unreachable.)

Comment: Scenario in the question: OP executed a playbook, a handler failed, OP fixed the handler. How does "force handler" option help OP in this situation?

Comment: As I see the question, not a handler failed, but rather some task in a playbook that prevented delayed handler to be executed.

Comment: Okaaay, so you interpreted "doesn't work" as "doesn't fire"... Not impossible.

Comment: Still it doesn't help post factum :-P ..."*How execute **again** a Ansible Playbook*"

Comment: Yes, this answer doesn't work for me.... the force-handler option will fire the handle only if the task is executed. In my case the task is considered done by Ansible so the handler is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

By default all handlers execute just once in play.
You must set another play:

```
- name: Play1
  tasks:
    ...
  handlers:
    ...
- name: Play2
  tasks:
    ...
  handlers:
    ...
```

Or... you must change environment. set var **force_handlers = True**
Or... **--force-handlers**